# Send a structure containing a string by UDP

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, udp

I've created a structure containing some strings :

```
typedef struct sc_message {
    int32_t across_conf;
    char domain[16];
    char fl_phase[16];
} sc_message;
```

I've always believed that `char` arrays, like any other arrays in C, were actually pointers to the first byte of the string.

I initiate the strings with `strncpy()` function, and I use this structure as a message to be sent with `sendto()` function.

The result works perfectly, I analyzed the packets sent by the program with Wireshark, the strings contents are effectively sent.

But when I read my code again, I realized that, according to my previous theory, only the addresses of the pointers are stored in the structure and should be sent, not the content itself. Apparently I am wrong, or I miss something.

Could somebody explain how it is possible ?

Comment: Arrays are not pointers!

Comment: I thought a `char[]` variable could be considered like a `char *` variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you add an array as a member in a `struct`, the array is actually included in the `struct`, not just a pointer to the array.

There are many differences and similarities between arrays and pointers, you can find answers to many common questions here: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/

Comment: Thanks, I learned a lot with the link you posted, which responds exactly to my question.